# Using the repository pattern with Dapper and a single accessor object

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

We are using Dapper as our ORM and have chosen the repository pattern for organizing our operations. This has worked very well for us but I'd like to confirm that this configuration is capable of sharing and disposing of SQL connections properly.

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddScoped(_ => new DeploymentManagerDbConnection(
    new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DeploymentManagement"))
));

services.AddScoped<IDeploymentManagerDbContext, DeploymentManagerDbContext>();
services.AddTransient<IChangeRequestRepository, ChangeRequestRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IBuildRepository, BuildRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IBatchRepository, BatchRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
```

**DeploymentManagerDbConnection.cs**

```
public DeploymentManagerDbConnection(IDbConnection dbConnection) : base(dbConnection)
{

}
```

**DbConnection.cs**

```
public class DbConnection : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed;

    public DbConnection(IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
        Connection = dbConnection;
    }

    public IDbConnection Connection { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
            if (disposing)
                Connection.Dispose();
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

**DeploymentManagerDbContext.cs**

```
public class DeploymentManagerDbContext : IDeploymentManagerDbContext
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public DeploymentManagerDbContext(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IChangeRequestRepository ChangeRequests =>
        _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IChangeRequestRepository)) as IChangeRequestRepository;

    public IBuildRepository Build =>
        _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IBuildRepository)) as IBuildRepository;

    public IBatchRepository Batch =>
        _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IBatchRepository)) as IBatchRepository;

    public IUserRepository Users =>
        _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IUserRepository)) as IUserRepository;
}
```

**UserRepository.cs**

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;

    public UserRepository(DeploymentManagerDbConnection deploymentManagerDbConnection)
    {
        _dbConnection = deploymentManagerDbConnection?.Connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommand moving the `Startup` code into an extension or you can put it under a namespace, and use Reflection to get all instances and register them, try to automate things. The connectionString should be used inside the `DeploymentManagerDbContext` and not the `Repository`. if used on `Repository` then what purpose the `DeploymentManagerDbContext` serves ?

Answer (score 3):

**Extra boiler plating**

To start with unless there is missing code from `DeploymentManagerDbConnection.cs` or `DbConnection.cs` they aren't doing anything interesting or cleaver with the underlying `IDbConnction` you're wrapping. If anything I would say to directly use it as is.

- **Startup.cs**

```
services.AddScoped<IDbConnection>(_ => 
    new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DeploymentManagement"))
));
```

- **UserRepository.cs**

```
public UserRepository(IDbConnection connection)
{
    _dbConnection = connection;
}
```

**Using `IServiceProvider` outside of `Startup.cs`**

In almost all cases it isn't recommended to be accessing the di container directly. Registrations or dynamic factories should know about the container `IServiceProvider`, but other wise it really shouldn't leak out to other places.

That being said `DeploymentManagerDbContext` *looks* like a factory but is far too simple to justify `IServiceProvider` leaking.

- **Register Disposables as `Func<T>`**

To preface, I would expect your interfaces like `IUserRepository` to inherit from `IDisposable` and in turn would call the dispose method on your `IDbConnection`.

What I would expect for your use-case for your repositories, you want to build them at runtime where ever you need them, but also want to follow/use DI to wire them up correctly. This is where `Func<T>` comes in.

- **Startup.cs**

```
services.AddTransient<IBuildRepository, BuildRepository>();
services.AddTransient<Func<IBuildRepository>>(_ => _.GetService<IBuildRepository>);
```

If you find you're seeing a bit of duplication, an extension method can cut down on this.

- **RegistrationExtentions.cs**

```
public static IServiceCollection AddRepository<TInterface, TImplimentation>(this IServiceCollection services)
    where TInterface : class
    where TImplimentation: TInterface
{
    services.AddTransient<TInterface, TImplimentation>();
    services.AddTransient<Func<TInterface>>(_ => _.GetService<TInterface>);
    return services;
}
```

However, if you don't want to create helper functions for this type of extra registrations, I'd recommend using `Lamar` as it auto-adds a type build rule for `Func<T>` and even `Lazy<T>`.

- **Startup.cs**

```
services.AddRepository<IBuildRepository, BuildRepository>()
    .AddRepository<IBatchRepository, BatchRepository>();
```

- **Back to DeploymentManagerDbContext**

We can now directly ask from the container for a **Buildable** repository.

```
//this class is also entirely optional to keep or throw
public class DeploymentManagerDbContext : IDeploymentManagerDbContext
{

    public DeploymentManagerDbContext(
    Func<IChangeRequestRepository> change,
    Func<IBuildRepository> build,
    Func<IBatchRepository> batch,
    Func<IUserRepository> user)
    {
        _change = change;
        _build = build;
        _batch = batch;
        _user = user;
    }
    
    private readonly Func<IChangeRequestRepository> _change;
    public IChangeRequestRepository ChangeRequests => _change();
    //skipping the other 3, just follow the pattern
}
```

- **Usage**
  Now in any code file you can directly ask for what you want built.

```
public class ProcessController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDeploymentManagerDbContext _contextFactory;
    public ProcessController(IDeploymentManagerDbContext contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
         using userContext = _contextFactory.Users;
         //sample only for this purpose there are better ways to do authentication
         userContext.IsValidUser(Request.Context.CurrentUser);

         using buildContext = _contextFactory.Build;
         buildContext.BuildFoo();

         using batchContext = _contextFactory.Batch;
         batchContext.BatchBar();
    }
}
```

- **Without `IDeploymentManagerDbContext`**
  Since the registrations are at the DI level you can also just directly ask for a specific builder.

```
public class ProcessController : Controller
{
    //skipping other fields
    private readonly Func<IBuildRepository> _build;
    public ProcessController(
    Func<IBuildRepository> build,
    Func<IBatchRepository> batch,
    Func<IUserRepository> user)
    {
        //skipping assignments
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
         using userContext = _users();
         //sample only for this purpose there are better ways to do authentication
         userContext.IsValidUser(Request.Context.CurrentUser);

         using buildContext = _build();
         buildContext.BuildFoo();

         using batchContext = _batch();
         batchContext.BatchBar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Michael Rieger. Thanks for your review. Just to clarify, `DeploymentManagerDbConnection` exists to create separation between multiple database connections. The database connection may not be the same between these repositories so by specifying `DeploymentManagerDbConnection` instead of `SomeOtherDbConnection`, the idea was that DI would be able to inject the appropriate connection. Do you have any thoughts on this approach?

Comment: @AdamChubbuck  doing this in 3 parts
  it might be a bit of a leaky abstraction where a class knows which implementation of an interface to use but the sample from  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44177920/3846633) does what you expect without extra hoops while still keeping this stuff in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48387767/3846633) can look simpler  but introduces a lot of redundant types., but had the benefit of types don't directly try to say *i want the `SpecificImplimentation` for interface x*

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52122571/3846633) is more direct by only adding 1 extra type but make you implement some property to tag/filter the right implementation you want.

Comment: Thanks again @Michael Rieger. For the extension above, were you able to test that? It looks like it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm also still curious if `IDeploymentManagerDbContext` should be Scoped

Comment: @AdamChubbuck function fixed, partially going off of memory there. I typically use `Lamar` like I suggested as an alternative. 

as for `IDeploymentManagerDbContext` ... it really won't make a difference either way since the `.Built` or `.Batch` and such always make *new* instances at that line call. In fact it could even be `Singleton` to maybe gain limited perf gains of making this builder/factory only once

Comment: No problem @Michael Rieger. So just to sum everything up, the repository interfaces should implement IDisposable and be added as transients. IDeploymentManagerDbContext should be injected as scoped, although it doesn't really matter much since the associated repositories will be retrieved as new instances regardless. And DeploymentManagerDbConnection and DbConnection can be removed in favor of a transient IDBConnection instance.

Comment: @AdamChubbuck you got it. 
the repositories are things we want to leverage the DI to build, but still follow the expected disposable behavior.

then the extra classes don't need to be in place since we've resolved where and when the service collection gets used, while keeping relevant things visible where you would expect to find them.

Comment: Wonderful. This makes a lot of sense. The only other change that I did need to make was to turn IDbConnection into a transient since when it was scoped, the connection wouldn't be available for subsequent requests. I'll be doing plenty of testing today to make sure there are no faults but I think I'm back on the right track. :)

Comment: Oddly, I am seeing errors stating "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.".